# How to move a drupal 6 installation to a new server?

Tags: 6, migrations

I backed up my files and database. uploaded files to new server, created and restored the database to the new server, edited the settings.php file. I navigate to the site, it pops up perfectly. I try to navigate to any other page and I get a 404 page not found error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a php.ini file and disable "register_globals" on the 1and1 server.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `mod_rewrite` for Apache enabled/installed?  If not, verify this is the case.

Also, ensure that your .htaccess file in your Drupal root is unchanged from the old server.

If you're on a Debian-based distribution, go to `/etc/apache2/mods-available` to verify that `rewrite.load` is present.  Then go to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` to verify that rewrite.load is symlinked in that directory.

If you're on a RedHat distro like CentOS, then go to `/etc/httpd/modules` and look for `mod_rewrite.so`.  Then, open up `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and verify that this line is in there `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`.

Comment: how do i verify that? My .htaccess file is exactly the same as before.

Comment: Is your server debian or redhat-based?

Comment: Not sure, I'm using 1and1.com web server. Inside the .htaccess file I appears that mod_rewrite is turned on.

Comment: So that's not the issue.  Are you using clean URLs?

Comment: Think of a path that you know should work... so `http://mysite.com/path/to/page` and change it to `http://mysite.com/?q=path/to/page` and let me know what happens.

Comment: Something else to check on, it sounds like you don't have access to the Apache VirtualHost configuration... it is imperative that the `AllowOverride` objective is set so that it picks up your .htaccess settings.

Comment: I was using Clean URLs on my last server, and Yes, I can navigate to every page with the "?q=path" method.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the rewrite mode enable? If not, try enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied the .htaccess file? Sometimes, it is not copied, because files stating with an `.` are regarded invisible and non archive

Have you got

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```

in your .htaccess?